# Scala: How to Define an Argument with Default Value in Partial Functions

Tags: scala

Given the following `PartialFunction`...

```
type MyFunc = PartialFunction[(Int, Int), String]

...

val myFunc = MyFunc {
  case (i, j) => (i + j).toString
}

...

myFunc(3, 2) // returns "5"
```

... is there a way to have a default value for the second argument (`j`)? The only way I've found so far is something like this:

```
type MyFunc = PartialFunction[Int, String]

...

def myFunc(j: Int = 10) = MyFunc {
  case i => (i + j).toString
}

...

myFunc()(5)  // returns "15"
myFunc(5)(2) // returns "7"
```

The solution above implies a different `PartialFunction` and a methods that takes an argument with default value... but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, how about this one?

```
object WrapperFunc { 
  val f = PartialFunction[(Int, Int), String] { 
    case (i,j) => (i + j).toString 
  }
 def apply(a: Int, b: Int = 5) = f (a,b) 
}
WrapperFunc(1)
WrapperFunc(1,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

methods can have default parameters, but functions can't.

your second `def myFunc` is a method (so it can have optional parameters), but you can't expand that into a function.

```
def mymethod(j: Int = 10) = MyFunc {
  case i => (i + j).toString
}

val asFunc = mymethod _
```

would lose the default parameter.

If you want to have something like this, you're going to need something like

```
type MyFunc = PartialFunction[(Option[Int], Int), String]

val myFunc = MyFunc {
  val mydefault = 10
  case (i, j) => (i.getOrElse(mydefault) + j).toString
}
```

and call it as `myfunc((Some(8), 3))` or `myfunc((None, 3))`